# How do I make a http request to an api which needs an password without writing my password in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, spring, security, authentication, xmlhttprequest

I have a spring boot application, which works as an api. If requested, it returns json data from my db. Now I want to run a website where I use the data I recived from my api. I thought of using Spring Security to authenticate the user, who wants to get my data. On the client side, the only solution I know, is to write the username and password for the authentication in my Javascript file and to send it to the api. The problem is, that everyone would be able to read it, if I run the website. Is there any other solution to solve that?

```
function req(method, url){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();                     
    xmlhttp.open(method, url, false);`
    //And somehow also sent username and password here
    xmlhttp.send(); 
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        return JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Never store credentials inside static code files. You can enter the username/password through a form, And then use jwt/cookie to manage authentication and authorization

Comment: But wouldn't it be the same if I use jwt. I mean wouldn't I have to write the token im my code?

Comment: Once you authenticate the user, your server will return a JWT signed with a private key to the client. You will keep this jwt in memory (or in a cookie that is sent on every request). You will include the jwt in each request so that the server can authenticate you. I'm not familiar with spring too much so i cant tell you about implementation. But im sure there are libraries for working with jwt on spring. (So you are not writing any sensitive data in the code, just storing it in a variable at runtime)

Comment: My problem is, that I don't know how to authenticate the user. I want to call the api via url in my code, so I have to pass the authentification data there. But how? If I write my username and password, everyone would be able to see them.

Comment: You dont access an API endpoint that requires authentication by passing a hardcoded password in your code. This is why you use a login/authentication form in your application. You have to get the password at runtime (using a form), and THEN access your api. You either create a form in your app and handle authentication yourself, or use a OAuth service like google to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using another method for securing your API, like JWT. Here's a good example to follow: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-security-json-web-tokenjwt-hello-world